# How to store array with Ecto using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to store an array of floating point values with Ecto using Postgres.
I'm using Ecto with the Phoenix Framework and Elixir.

How would I define my model and migration for this?

I haven't tried much, except searching the web, which didn't find anything useful :-(

I did try defining a model with a schema like this:

```
  schema "my_model" do
    field :my_array, :array

    timestamps
  end
```

which gave an error "invalid or unknown type :array for field :my_array"

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I found the answer in the list of primitive types for Ecto.Schema here:

[Ecto.Schema](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html)

The answer is to define the type like this:

```
  schema "my_model" do
    field :my_array, {:array, :float}

    timestamps
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, how would you write the migration for that?

Comment: Here is a generator example: `mix phx.gen.schema Blog.Post blog_posts tags:array:string`

Comment: The example from @sash generates a migration with the relevant line `add :tags, {:array, :string}`

Answer (score 49):

As Josh wrote use the array type from [Ecto.Schema](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#module-types-and-casting)

In the model:

```
schema "my_model" do
  field :my_array, {:array, inner_type}
end
```

@neildaemond Migration:

```
alter table(:my_models) do
  add :my_array, {:array, inner_type}
end
```

Replace `inner_type` with one of the valid types, such as `:string`.

You can also do the same thing with a `map` type:

```
schema "my_model" do
  field :my_map, {:map, inner_type}
end
```

Comment: Any idea how to properly construct a form that would let someone input the elements of this array or map?

Comment: @pmarreck have you looked at Form docs? https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html
I usually work on an API apps so I don't use forms and can't help

Comment: I have, don't see anything helpful there in this case

Comment: @pmarreck This post seems to be relevant.